# how to send multiple data to mutation in apollo graphql

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I want to dynamically send multiple of data(array of objects) from input to apollo graphql mutation, but haven't found a way that works.
Now I'm still writing it manually like the code example below.

**sample code I made:**

**Mutation**

```
mutation createData(
  $userId: Int!, 
  $Content: String, 
  $Title: String
) {
    createData(
      input: {
        content: $Content
        filterMetas: [
          // how to make this dynamic from user input?
          { categoryName: "Category Name 1", categoryId: "1", categoryType: INFO }
          { categoryName: "Category Name 2", categoryId: "2", categoryType: INFO }
        ]
        meta: { title: $Title }
      }
      userId: $userId
    ) {
      id
      name
}
```

**calling mutation in react**

```
CreateData({
   variables: {
     Content: content,
     Title: title,
     // how to send multiple filtersMetas(array of objects) from here? instead of entering it manually
   },
   context: { clientName: API_CLIENT },
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: like any other variable, you can even send all using one variable, entire `$input`

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved. I changed the `FilterMetas` to be like the type in the graphql server

```
mutation createData(
  $userId: Int!, 
  $Content: String, 
  $Title: String
  $FilterMetas: [FilterMetaInput!]
) {
    createData(
      input: {
        content: $Content
        filterMetas: $FilterMetas
      }
      userId: $userId
    ) {
      id
      name
}
```